# Bash: pair up two series of files

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have a number of files with this pattern:

```
file1_foo.ext
file1_bar.ext
file2_foo.ext
file2_bar.ext
```

and so on.

I need to "pair them" and put them in a file like this

```
file1_foo.txt    file1_bar.txt
```

(tab separated)

What's the best course of action in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you don't want to just assume both exist. This will only print the lines if they both exist.

```
for file1 in *_foo.ext; do
    file2="${file1%foo.ext}bar.ext"
    if [[ -e "$file2" ]]; then
        printf '%s\t%s\n' "$file1" "$file2"
    fi
done
```

Sample:

```
$ tee {1,2,3}_foo.ext {1,3,4}_bar.ext </dev/null >/dev/null
$ ./script
1_foo.ext   1_bar.ext
3_foo.ext   3_bar.ext
```

Comment: Right, I forgot about % and extensions. I'll test this at once.